# Where is a good place to ask questions about Database-Models?

Tags: database-design, architecture, chat, forum

I'm developing a browsergame on my own and have problems with the database-model.

Where would be a good place to solve my problems?

I don't think here would be the best place for this, but i really can't find a place, where i can discuss such problems.

In most places you only can ask specific questions like "how to normalize table A" but if you ask questions like "how would you put a contest like UEFA-Championsleague into a database(teams, players, qualification, groups, finals)" you only get an answer like "please be more specific".

I'm searching for a community with people who willingly discuss such problems.

Can you hint me in the right direction?

Comment: If you're creating a game, you might want to check gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: ask this on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ - or https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19727/browser-game-database-structure

try there ... it's dedicated to gamedev